# Is partial differentiation not available in wolframalpha?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wolfram-alpha

The following sets do not match.

```
D[(a*x+b*y[x]-x*(a*x+b*y[x])-y*(c*x + d*y[x]))*x, {x,1}]

(correct answer)
(a x + b y - x (a x + b y) - y (c x + d y) )
　　　　　　　　　+ (a - b - 2 a x - b y + b x - c y + c x + 2 d y) x

(wolfram output) => Different from the above.
```

Is this something that happens in general?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to write this.
Please calculate under the condition of dy / dx = -1.

Comment: just replace `y[x]` by `z-x` in your expressions

Comment: ```Out[1]=
4+ax+b(-x+z)-x(ax+b(-x+z))-(-x+z)(cx+d(-x+z))+x(a-b-ax-(a-b)x+cx-b(-x+z)-(c-d)(-x+z)+d(-x+z)) ```

This is the result of the replacement.
What will this '4' do for me?

Comment: Ah ok. Then what you want to do is to compute the derivative as usual and replace $y'(x)$ by $-1$ (and $y[x]$ by $y$ if you want it to look just as you specify). You can do this by adding [ ./ (replacement-rule) ] for example D[(a*x + b*y[x] - x*(a*x + b*y[x]) - y[x]*(c*x + d*y[x]))*x, {x, 1}] /. y'[x] -> -1 /. y[x] -> y

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5BSin%5Bx*y%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C2%7D%5D) of
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left[\sin(xy)\right]
 = -y^2 \sin(xy)
$$
via Wolfram Alpha, so partial differentiation does work.

[Here is another one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%28a*x%2Bb*y%5Bx%5D%29*x%2C+%7Bx%2C1%7D%5D) related to your query, just not that complex:
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left[(ax+by(x))\cdot x\right]
 = 2ax + by(x) + bxy'(x)
$$
so seems to work as well.